# fullcalendar script call a GET php variable to get mysql data doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

im having problems with this code:

```
<?php
// Require DB Connection
require_once('connect.php');
// Get ALl Event
$er = 1;
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE id_user = $er AND events.date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY events.date ASC");
$sth->execute(array($_GET['start'], $_GET['end']));
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

When i past the variable `$er` with this value works perfect! but when i pass a `$_GET['cu']` fails, someone can tell me what is happened?

Note: `$_GET['cu']` is a value that i take from the URL `http://..../?cu=1`

And this file is calling from a js script of Fullcalendar in the events:

```
// Get all events stored in database
        events: 'crud/getEvents.php',
```

Comment: How does your page gets called ?

Comment: Where is $_GET['cu'] coming from? I don't see it in your code, and I don't see anything related in the URL you're using. Please explain with an example which shows you using it

Comment: Also ... `WHERE id_user = $er` ... the `$er` should be replaced with a parameter and moved to the array passed in to "execute". You need to parameterise **all** your incoming values, not just some of them.

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you. i upload the proyect to this url so you can see it complete:
https://github.com/getweb-agency/fullcalendar-crud-filter.git

Comment: ADyson, the $_GET['cu'] is coming from a link to this page and when you go to the calendar the url look like this URL http://..path../?cu=1 with the cu variable.

Comment: Ok so if I understand you, you want that to be passed to your events URL as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank everyone, the solution was:

to the main.js add this function to get the URL data:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
```

and in the events:

```
    events: 'crud/getEvents.php?cu='+getParameterByName('cu'),
```

so in the file getEvents we can call the variable:

```
// Get ALl Event
$er = $_GET['cu'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE id_user = $er AND events.date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY events.date ASC");
```

Comment: You still need to parameterise the $er variable properly

Comment: P.S. all the "getParameterByName" regexes and other complexity could be removed and simplfied by using the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) .